# How to perform n number of operations parallely in rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have a scenario. I am getting data from different sources in different time. I need to perform some intensive work on those data parallely on a background thread and get the result on the main thread. I thought of using `BehaviorSubject`. But I am not able to figure out how will I do the operation parallely and return the result back to main thread. Since `subscribeOn` doesn't have any effect in `Subjects` so I wont be able to perform the operation in background thread. Am I missing something to connect?

Comment: Do you need all results at once or process each result when it comes?

Comment: each result when it comes. @ror

Comment: you should then be using http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html

Comment: But how I dynamically add observable to `merge`? My data comes from different sources at different time.

Comment: If you provide example of where your data comes from (and how do you create that observable), I should be able to update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this pls:

```
Observable.merge(
                Observable.just(1, 2, 3).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
                Observable.just("4", "5", "6").subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        )
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to take a look to [ParallelFlowable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Parallel-flows) and to try the example below

```
someFlowable
    .parallel(NUMBER_OF_THREADS)
    .runOn(scheduler)
    .doOnNext(this::doSomeWork)
    .sequential()
    .subscribe{ result -> ... }
```